# Decoding the Base64 string in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am developing a web API in which I am sending data from the app in JSON format which contains an image as a base64 string that I need to decode on the server.

Below is the code where I am decoding the string

```
def imageString=object.image
Base64 coder = new Base64()
def decode=coder.decode(imageString)
```

which throws this error:

> Cannot cast object '[B@6aec0bd1' with class '[B' to class 'javax.ws.rs.core.Response'. Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: Cannot cast object '[B@6aec0bd1' with class '[B' to class 'javax.ws.rs.core.Response'

What is a possible solution for this?

Comment: where this error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a base64 encoded string, you can convert it to a byte array with this:

```
def imageString
def byteArray = imageString.decodeBase64()
```

However, in your exception `object.image` already seems to be a byte array, not a string: the java type descriptor `[B` indicates an array of primitive bytes.  This suggests it might already have been converted from base64 somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def imageString=object.image 
Base64 coder = new Base64()
byte[] decoded=coder.decodeBase64(imageString)
String s == new String(decoded)
```